# onChange event not firing in IE8 when switching active Window

Tags: java, html, xhtml, richfaces

I have a weird problem, which is probably a bug in IE8, but I am seeking for a workaround.

**Description of the UI:**

I have a form that displays many rows. When the user enter a value in one of the row, it will perform some basic validation and then it will add a "delete" link next to it. (the goal is to delete the entered row).

**Description of the problem:**

- User enter some data
- User switch window (go in any other IE tab or even switch to another software, like notepad)
- come back to IE, and enter another row

  --> The "onchange" event is not fired when the user clicks elsewhere.

This works fine with Chrome or other browsers (the event is fired normally even if we switch window).

**Workaround**
 - before switching to another software, if the user just press tab or click in another cell, the "onchange" event works as expected.

Anybody got a similar problem, or know another method that would do simiar behavior and work in all browsers?

Here is the code:

```
<rich:column>
    <h:inputText id="batchSaid" value="#{currentBatch.batchSaid}" onkeypress="enableValidateitemsButton(this);" 
                onblur="validateCase(this,'MYVALUE');enableValidateitemsButton(this);">
        <a4j:support event="onchange" process="batchAdd" action="#{itemsPageFormImpl.enableValidateBtnDisableActivateBtn(currentBatch, tRowId)}" 
                reRender="deleteBatchLink, deleteBatchLinkId" ajaxSingle="true"/>
    </h:inputText>
</rich:column>
<rich:column id="deleteBatchLinkId">
    <div align="right">
        <a4j:commandLink id="deleteBatchLink" style="font-weight:bold;" value="Delete" action="#{itemsPageFormImpl.deletBatch}" reRender="batchdataTable" 
                rendered="#{currentBatch.showBatchRowDelBtn}" ajaxSingle="true">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{itemsPageFormImpl.deleteBatchId}" value="#{currentBatch.batchId}" />
        </a4j:commandLink>
    </div>
</rich:column>
```

The problem is with the deleteBatchLink not being displayed.

Comment: A way to solve it is to show a big shiny link called "install a decent browser by clicking here" to your users ;-)

Comment: Nice thought, but unfortunatlely I have to support IE8... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We finally never found a solution to this. The users uses the workaround.